# convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any simple way to convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm using jquery?

Note: not using any other libraries.

I have a `var time = $("#starttime").val()` that returns a hh:mm AM/PM.

Comment: `if (hour < 12) hour = hour + 12;`

Comment: If you add a special case for 12:xx AM (subtract 12) then this is correct for all PM hours. For all other AM hours, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this

```
var time = $("#starttime").val();
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
```

Comment: Fails for example for 10pm

Comment: OP specifically asked for hh:mm XX format, so 10pm should be 10:00 PM, and it will work

Comment: `if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = 0;` is more straightforward I guess

Comment: I would also recommend `(AMPM.toLowerCase() == "am")`

Comment: Your answer just saved me at the edge of the moment man.. keep up this good work.. thanks for the answer.. actually i need to deliver my proj in another 10 minutes, but i am taking seconds to appreciate you

Comment: This returns `['12', '30']` for both `12:30 am` and `12:30 pm`.

Comment: This is supposed to work with "AM" and "PM" rather than "am" and "pm". In order to make it case insensitive, you'll have to add `.toUpperCase(...)` at the end of line 1

Answer (score 97):

This question needs a newer answer :)

```js
const convertTime12to24 = (time12h) => {
  const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');

  let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');

  if (hours === '12') {
    hours = '00';
  }

  if (modifier === 'PM') {
    hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
  }

  return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 AM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:59 AM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 PM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:59 PM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('01:02 PM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('05:06 PM'));
```

Comment: if (hours === '12') {
    hours = '00';
  }

Don't you also want to check the modifier here? (AM or PM)

 if (hours === '12' && modifier === 'AM') {
    hours = '00';
  }

Comment: @GregRTaylor No, then it would output eg. `24:12` for `12:12 PM`.

Comment: I like this solution better than the others because 1) it simplifies the logic in two separate steps which are easier to understand and follow for humans, and 2) checks whether it's AM/PM or if `hours=12` once

Comment: The code is wrong for the 12:00 AM exemple : fix 
 if (hours === '12' && modifier === 'PM') {
    hours = '00';
  } , PM = post meridiem so afternoon

Comment: @snow maybe answer has been changed but now it gives 00:00 for 12 AM so it seems to be working with no issue

Comment: @Learner it has not been changed. It has been working correctly :)

Comment: LOL then guys didn't test right at the first place, i guess

Comment: You can also split it as `let [hours, minutes, modifier] = time12h.split(/\W+/);` at once.

Comment: what if there is no space b/w time and modifier
e.g: '05:06PM'

Comment: @RabindraKumarMahato then you could split the string at specific positions :)

Comment: The conversion of hours is much shorter as `(hours % 12) + (/am/i.test(modifier)? 0: 12)` which reduces the function body to 2 lines.

Comment: @RobG Interesting solution! However, my proposal looks very, very simple and I think that's its huge advantage!

Comment: nice answer can't see any problems - although working out if it was correct or not hurt at times! improved your tests to hit all edge cases

Answer (score 22):

This will help :

```
 function getTwentyFourHourTime(amPmString) { 
        var d = new Date("1/1/2013 " + amPmString); 
        return d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes(); 
    }
```

**Example :**

```
getTwentyFourHourTime("8:45 PM"); // "20:45"
getTwentyFourHourTime("8:45 AM"); // "8:45"
```

**Update :**
Note : There should be a space for timestring between "Time" and "am/pm".

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Timestamp_string) using the Date constructor with a string "is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies".

Comment: This relies on implementation dependent behaviour to parse the timestamp. It also doesn't pad single digit minutes so is really h:m.

Answer (score 21):

I had to do something similar but I was generating a `Date` object so I ended up making a function like this:

```
function convertTo24Hour(time) {
    var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
    if(time.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
        time = time.replace('12', '0');
    }
    if(time.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
        time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
    }
    return time.replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
}
```

I think this reads a little easier.  You feed a string in the format h:mm am/pm.

```
    var time = convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase());
    var date = new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + time);
```

Examples:

```
        $("#startday").val('7/10/2013');

        $("#starttime").val('12:00am');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

        $("#starttime").val('12:00pm');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

        $("#starttime").val('1:00am');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

        $("#starttime").val('12:12am');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 00:12:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

        $("#starttime").val('3:12am');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 03:12:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

        $("#starttime").val('9:12pm');
        new Date($("#startday").val() + ' ' + convertTo24Hour($("#starttime").val().toLowerCase()));
        Wed Jul 10 2013 21:12:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: there is a bug when AM or PM are in capital letters

Answer (score 12):

Here my solution **including seconds**:

```
function convert_to_24h(time_str) {
    // Convert a string like 10:05:23 PM to 24h format, returns like [22,5,23]
    var time = time_str.match(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) (\w)/);
    var hours = Number(time[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time[2]);
    var seconds = Number(time[3]);
    var meridian = time[4].toLowerCase();

    if (meridian == 'p' && hours < 12) {
      hours += 12;
    }
    else if (meridian == 'a' && hours == 12) {
      hours -= 12;
    }
    return [hours, minutes, seconds];
  };
```

Comment: `hours += 12` and `hours -= 12` :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
function timeConversion(s) {
  var time = s.toLowerCase().split(':');
  var hours = parseInt(time[0]);
  var _ampm = time[2];
  if (_ampm.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
    time[0] = '00';
  }
  if (_ampm.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
    time[0] = hours + 12;
  }
  return time.join(':').replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
}
```

Call the function with string params:

```
timeConversion('17:05:45AM')
```

or

```
timeConversion('07:05:45PM')
```

Answer (score 4):

i must recommend a library: [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

code:

```
var target12 = '2016-12-08 9:32:45 PM';
console.log(moment(target12, 'YYYY-MM-DD h:m:s A').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

Comment: I am not sure why this answer didn't get upvote but this is the most right way because moment takes care of timezone and everything for you! take my upvote

Comment: This should be a comment. An answer should not require the use of a library that isn't not tagged or mentioned in the OP, otherwise there could be many duplicate answers using different libraries. It also requires the OP to learn the library, not to mention that libraries can become unsupported or deprecated (moment.js is currently no longer being developed and may be deprecated in time).

Answer (score 4):

An extended version of @krzysztof answer with the ability to work on time that has space or not between time and modifier, can use uppercase and lowercase for the modifier.

```js
function convertTime12to24(time12h) {
    let [hours, minutes, modifier] = time12h.match(/(\d+|pm|am)/gi);

    if (hours === '12') {
        hours = '00';
    }

    if (modifier.toLowerCase() === 'pm') {
        hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
    }

    return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 PM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 pm'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00pm'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 AM'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00 am'));
console.log(convertTime12to24('12:00am'));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you're looking for a solution that converts ANY FORMAT to 24 hours HH:MM correctly.

```js
function get24hTime(str) {
    str = String(str).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    var has_am = str.indexOf('am') >= 0;
    var has_pm = str.indexOf('pm') >= 0;
    // first strip off the am/pm, leave it either hour or hour:minute
    str = str.replace('am', '').replace('pm', '');
    // if hour, convert to hour:00
    if (str.indexOf(':') < 0) str = str + ':00';
    // now it's hour:minute
    // we add am/pm back if striped out before 
    if (has_am) str += ' am';
    if (has_pm) str += ' pm';
    // now its either hour:minute, or hour:minute am/pm
    // put it in a date object, it will convert to 24 hours format for us 
    var d = new Date("1/1/2011 " + str);
    // make hours and minutes double digits
    var doubleDigits = function(n) {
        return (parseInt(n) < 10) ? "0" + n : String(n);
    };
    return doubleDigits(d.getHours()) + ':' + doubleDigits(d.getMinutes());
}

console.log(get24hTime('6')); // 06:00
console.log(get24hTime('6am')); // 06:00
console.log(get24hTime('6pm')); // 18:00
console.log(get24hTime('6:11pm')); // 18:11
console.log(get24hTime('6:11')); // 06:11
console.log(get24hTime('18')); // 18:00
console.log(get24hTime('18:11')); // 18:11
```

Answer (score 3):

For anybody reading this in the future, here is a simpler answer:

```
var s = "11:41:02PM";
var time = s.match(/\d{2}/g);
if (time[0] === "12") time[0] = "00";
if (s.indexOf("PM") > -1) time[0] = parseInt(time[0])+12;
return time.join(":");
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert a time from **12-hour format to 24-hour format** using **Moment.js** in jQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const time12 = '02:30 PM'; // Replace this with your 12-hour time string
    const time24 = moment(time12, 'hh:mm A').format('HH:mm');
    console.log(time24);
  });
</script>
```

Replace '02:30 PM' in the code with your desired 12-hour time string. When you run this script, it will output the converted time in the 24-hour format.

Remember to include jQuery and the Moment.js library in your HTML file before running this code. You can include jQuery similarly to how you include the Moment.js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed this function for a project. I tried devnull69's but I was having some trouble, mostly because the string input is very specific for the am/pm section and I would've needed to change my validation. I messed around with Adrian P.'s jsfiddle and ended up with a version that seems to work better for a larger variety of date formats. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u91q8kmt/2/.

Here is the function:

```
function ConvertTimeformat(format, str) {
    var hours = Number(str.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(str.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = str.match(/\s?([AaPp][Mm]?)$/)[1];
    var pm = ['P', 'p', 'PM', 'pM', 'pm', 'Pm'];
    var am = ['A', 'a', 'AM', 'aM', 'am', 'Am'];
    if (pm.indexOf(AMPM) >= 0 && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (am.indexOf(AMPM) >= 0 && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    if (format == '0000') {
        return (sHours + sMinutes);
    } else if (format == '00:00') {
        return (sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will fail for any invalid values such as '99:99'

Comment: If you're paid by the character, this is a good answer. Otherwise, it's unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 2):

With this you can have the following:
Sample Input: **07:05:45PM**
Sample Output: **19:05:45**

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    let output = '';
    const timeSeparator = ':'
    const timeTokenType = s.substr(s.length - 2 , 2).toLowerCase();
    const timeArr = s.split(timeSeparator).map((timeToken) => {
    const isTimeTokenType = 
          timeToken.toLowerCase().indexOf('am') > 0 ||                                                                                               
           timeToken.toLowerCase().indexOf('pm');
        if(isTimeTokenType){
            return timeToken.substr(0, 2);
        } else {
            return timeToken;
        }
    });
    const hour = timeArr[0];
    const minutes = timeArr[1];
    const seconds = timeArr[2];
    const hourIn24 = (timeTokenType === 'am') ? parseInt(hour) - 12 : 
    parseInt(hour) + 12;
    return hourIn24.toString()+ timeSeparator + minutes + timeSeparator + seconds;
}
```

Hope you like it !

Answer (score 2):

Because all the answers so far seem to be verbose, here's a simple minimalist solution:

```js
/* Convert h:mm a/p to H:mm
 * i.e. 12 hour time to 24 hour time
 * @param {string} time - h:mm a/p format
 * @returns {string} time in H:mm format
 */
function to24HrTime(time) {
  let [hr, min, ap] = time.toLowerCase().match(/\d+|[a-z]+/g) || [];
  return `${(hr % 12) + (ap == 'am'? 0 : 12)}:${min}`;
}

['9:02 am',
 '9:02 pm',
 '9:02am',
 '9:02pm',
 '12:15 AM',
 '12:01 PM',
].forEach(time => console.log(`${time} -> ${to24HrTime(time)}`));
```

That assumes the input string has a suitable format and values. A more robust version is:

```js
/* Given 12 hr time, return24 hr time
 * @param {string} time - time in format h:mm am/pm
 *        h  must be in range 1 to 12
 *        mm must be in range 00 to 59
 *        am/pm is not case sensitive
 * @returns {string} time in 24 hr format H:mm
 *        H  in range 0 to 23
 *        mm in range 00 to 59
 *
 */
function to24HrTime(time = new Date().toLocaleString('en',{hour:'numeric', minute:'2-digit', hour12:true})) {
  let [hr, min, ap] = String(time).toLowerCase().match(/\d+|[a-z]+/g) || [];
  // If time is valid, return reformatted time
  // Otherwise return undefined
  return /^([1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d\s?(am|pm)/i.test(time)? `${(hr%12)+(ap=='am'?0:12)}:${min}` : void 0;
}

// Examples
// Without arguments
console.log(`No args -> ${to24HrTime()}`);
// Valid input
['9:02 am',
 '9:02 pm',
 '9:02am',
 '9:02pm',
 '12:15 AM',
 '12:01 PM',
 // Invalid input
 '12',       // Missing mins & ap
 '99:05 am', // hrs out of range
 '0:05 am',  // hrs out of range
 '9:60 am',  // mins out of range
 '9:09 pp',  // ap out of range
 {},         // Random object
].forEach(time => console.log(`${time} -> ${to24HrTime(time)}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

based on meeting [CodeSkill #1](http://www.codeskill.org/)

validation of format should be another function :)

```js
  

function convertTimeFrom12To24(timeStr) {
  var colon = timeStr.indexOf(':');
  var hours = timeStr.substr(0, colon),
      minutes = timeStr.substr(colon+1, 2),
      meridian = timeStr.substr(colon+4, 2).toUpperCase();
 
  
  var hoursInt = parseInt(hours, 10),
      offset = meridian == 'PM' ? 12 : 0;
  
  if (hoursInt === 12) {
    hoursInt = offset;
  } else {
    hoursInt += offset;
  }
  return hoursInt + ":" + minutes;
}
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("12:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("12:00 PM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("11:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("01:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("01:00 PM"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Converting AM/PM Time string to 24 Hours Format.**
Example 9:30 PM to 21:30

```
function get24HrsFrmAMPM(timeStr) {
    if (timeStr && timeStr.indexOf(' ') !== -1 && timeStr.indexOf(':') !== -1) {
        var hrs = 0;
        var tempAry = timeStr.split(' ');
        var hrsMinAry = tempAry[0].split(':');
        hrs = parseInt(hrsMinAry[0], 10);
        if ((tempAry[1] == 'AM' || tempAry[1] == 'am') && hrs == 12) {
            hrs = 0;
        } else if ((tempAry[1] == 'PM' || tempAry[1] == 'pm') && hrs != 12) {
            hrs += 12;
        }
        return ('0' + hrs).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + parseInt(hrsMinAry[1], 10)).slice(-2);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//here is my solution.
function timeConversion(s) {
        // Write your code here
        let amPM = s.indexOf('AM') !== -1 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        let tString = s.toString().replace(/AM|PM/gi,'');
        let splitTime = tString.split(':');
        let h = splitTime[0];
        let m = splitTime[1];
        let sec = splitTime[2];
        let twntyfr = amPM === 'PM' && parseInt(h) !== 12 ? parseInt(h)+12 : h;
        if(parseInt(twntyfr) === 12 && amPM === 'AM') twntyfr = '00';
        return twntyfr+':'+m+':'+sec;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HackerRank TimeConversion Solution

12-hour AM/PM format, to military (24-hour) time

```js
function timeConversion(s) {
    let time = 0
    let hour = s.slice(0, 2)
    let toD = s.slice(-2)

    if (toD === 'AM' && hour == 12) {
        time = `00${s.slice(2, s.length -2)}`
    } else {
        if (toD === 'PM' && hour < 12) {
            time = `${Number(12 + parseInt(hour))}${s.slice(2, s.length - 2)}`
        } else {
            time = s.slice(0, s.length - 2)
        }
    }

    return console.log(time)
}

timeConversion('12:00:17AM') // 00:00:17
timeConversion('09:21:33PM') // 21:21:33
timeConversion('12:43:53PM') // 12:43:53
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a time from 12-hour format to 24-hour format in a single line of code, you can use the Date object in JavaScript

```
const time12to24 = (time12) => new Date(`2023-07-27 ${time12}`).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
```

You can use this function time12to24 to convert a 12-hour format time string to a 24-hour format time string.

```
console.log(time12to24('02:30 PM')); // Output: "14:30:00"
console.log(time12to24('10:45 AM')); // Output: "10:45:00"
```

Please note that this code assumes the current date is "2023-07-27", which is used for parsing the time. The function will return the time in the format "HH:mm:ss" (hours, minutes, seconds).

Comment: this is the simplest solution imho, but be aware that your time format must be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bit of an adaptation of script @devnull69 submitted. I felt for my application it would be more useful as a function that returned the value that I could, then use as a variable.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="time_field" />
<button>Submit</submit>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function convertTime(time) {

        var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d\d?)/)[1]);
        var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d\d?)/)[1]);
        var AMPM = time.match(/\s(AM|PM)$/i)[1];

        if((AMPM == 'PM' || AMPM == 'pm') && hours < 12) {
            hours = hours + 12;
        }
        else if((AMPM == 'AM' || AMPM == "am") && hours == 12) {
            hours = hours - 12;
        }

        var sHours = hours.toString();
        var sMinutes = minutes.toString();

        if(hours < 10) {
            sHours = "0" + sHours;
        }
        else if(minutes < 10) {
             sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
        }

        return sHours + ":" + sMinutes;

    }

    $('button').click(function() {
        alert(convertTime($('#time_field').val()));
    });

});
```

Comment: Function is only working for `PM` time not `AM` time. [Example](http://jsbin.com/qovoyudunu/edit?js,output)

Comment: This is due to wrong operator priority regarding `||` and `&&`. It should be `if ( (AMPM == 'PM' || AMPM == 'pm') && hours<12)` and `else if ( (AMPM == 'AM' || AMPM == "am") && hours==12)`. Also the third regex is wrong. Try `var AMPM = time.match(/\s(AM|PM)$/i)[1];`. See fiddle: http://jsbin.com/xanubinoqi/edit?js,output

Comment: Great catches @devnull69. I've updated the code to reflect what you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getDisplayDatetime() {
    var d = new Date("February 04, 2011 19:00"),
     hh = d.getHours(),  mm = d.getMinutes(),  dd = "AM", h = hh;
    mm=(mm.toString().length == 1)? mm = "0" + mm:mm;
    h=(h>=12)?hh-12:h;
     dd=(hh>=12)?"PM":"AM";
    h=(h == 0)?12:h;
    var textvalue=document.getElementById("txt");
    textvalue.value=h + ":" + mm + " " + dd;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="getDisplayDatetime()">
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dateFormat.masks.armyTime= 'HH:MM';

now.format("armyTime");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertTo24Hour(time) {
    time = time.toUpperCase();
    var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
    if(time.indexOf('AM') != -1 && hours == 12) {
        time = time.replace('12', '0');
    }
    if(time.indexOf('PM')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
        time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
    }
    return time.replace(/(AM|PM)/, '');
}
```

Comment: Maybe is because you are not passing the parameter "time" correctly, this worked for me perfectly @MizAkita

Answer (score 0):

```
date --date="2:00:01 PM" +%T
14:00:01

date --date="2:00 PM" +%T | cut -d':' -f1-2
14:00

var="2:00:02 PM"
date --date="$var" +%T
14:00:02
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this more generic function:

```
function from12to24(hours, minutes, meridian) {
  let h = parseInt(hours, 10);
  const m = parseInt(minutes, 10);
  if (meridian.toUpperCase() === 'PM') {
    h = (h !== 12) ? h + 12 : h;
  } else {
    h = (h === 12) ? 0 : h;
  }
  return new Date((new Date()).setHours(h,m,0,0));
}
```

Note it uses some ES6 functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = "9:09:59AM"
var pmCheck = time.includes("PM");
var hrs = parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
var newtime = '';
// this is for between  12 AM to 12:59:59AM  = 00:00:00
if (hrs == 12 && pmCheck == false) {
    newtime = "00" + ':' + time.split(":")[1] + ':' + time.split(":")[2].replace("AM", '');
}
//this is for between  12 PM to 12:59:59 =12:00:00
else if (hrs == 12 && pmCheck == true) {
    newtime = "12" + ':' + time.split(":")[1] + ':' + time.split(":")[2].replace("PM", '');
}
//this is for between 1 AM and 11:59:59 AM
else if (!pmCheck) {
    newtime = hrs + ':' + time.split(":")[1] + ':' + time.split(":")[2].replace("AM", '');
}
//this is for between 1 PM and 11:59:59 PM
else if (pmCheck) {
    newtime = (hrs + 12) + ':' + time.split(":")[1] + ':' + time.split(":")[2].replace("PM", '');
}
console.log(newtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

single and easy js function for calc time meridian in real time

JS

```
   function convertTime24to12(time24h) {
                var timex = time24h.split(':');

                if(timex[0] !== undefined && timex [1] !== undefined)
                 {
                     var hor = parseInt(timex[0]) > 12 ? (parseInt(timex[0])-12) : timex[0] ;
                     var minu = timex[1];
                     var merid = parseInt(timex[0]) < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';

                     var res = hor+':'+minu+' '+merid;

                     document.getElementById('timeMeridian').innerHTML=res.toString();
                 }
            }
```

Html

```
 <label for="end-time">Hour <i id="timeMeridian"></i> </label>
            <input type="time" name="hora" placeholder="Hora" id="end-time" class="form-control" onkeyup="convertTime24to12(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript solution based off of @krzysztof-dąbrowski 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197728/563420)

```js
export interface HoursMinutes {
  hours: number;
  minutes: number;
}
export function convert12to24(time12h: string): HoursMinutes {
  const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');
  let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');

  if (hours === '12') {
    hours = '00';
  }

  if (minutes.length === 1) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }

  if (modifier.toUpperCase() === 'PM') {
    hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12 + '';
  }

  return {
    hours: parseInt(hours, 10),
    minutes: parseInt(minutes, 10)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested for all the use cases

```
function timeConversion(s) {
let h24;
let m24;
let sec24;

const splittedDate = s.split(":");
const h = parseInt(splittedDate[0], 10);
const m = parseInt(splittedDate[1], 10);
const sec = parseInt(splittedDate[2][0] + splittedDate[2][1], 10); 
const meridiem = splittedDate[2][2] + splittedDate[2][3];

if (meridiem === "AM") {
    if (h === 12) {
        h24 = '00';
    } else {
        h24 = h;
        if (h24 < 10) {
            h24 = '0' + h24;
        }
    }
    m24 = m;
    sec24 = sec;
} else if (meridiem === "PM") {
    if (h === 12) {
        h24 = h
    } else {
        h24 = h + 12;
        if (h24 < 10) {
            h24 = '0' + h24;
        }
    }
    m24 = m;
    sec24 = sec;
}


if (m24 < 10) {
    m24 = '0' + m24; 
} 

if (sec24 < 10) {
    sec24 = '0' + sec24;
}

  return h24 + ":" + m24 + ":" + sec24; 
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Muneebkhan/v25oebjn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Short ES6 code

```
const convertFrom12To24Format = (time12) => {
  const [sHours, minutes, period] = time12.match(/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2}) (AM|PM)/).slice(1);
  const PM = period === 'PM';
  const hours = (+sHours % 12) + (PM ? 12 : 0);

  return `${('0' + hours).slice(-2)}:${minutes}`;
}
```

```
const convertFrom24To12Format = (time24) => {
  const [sHours, minutes] = time24.match(/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})/).slice(1);
  const period = +sHours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
  const hours = +sHours % 12 || 12;

  return `${hours}:${minutes} ${period}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue on HackerRank, so I'm here to share my result

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    const isPM = s.indexOf('PM') !== -1;
    let [hours, minutes, seconds] = s.replace(isPM ? 'PM':'AM', '').split(':');

    if (isPM) {
        hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
        hours = hours === 24 ? 12 : hours;
    } else {
        hours = parseInt(hours, 10);
        hours = hours === 12 ? 0 : hours;
        if (String(hours).length === 1) hours = '0' + hours;
    }

    const time = [hours, minutes, seconds].join(':');

    return time;
}
```

This works for inputs like `06:40:03AM`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatto24(date) {
  let ampm = date.split(" ")[1];
  let time = date.split(" ")[0];
  if (ampm == "PM") {
    let hours = time.split(":")[0];
    let minutes = time.split(":")[1];
    let seconds = time.split(":")[2];
    let hours24 = JSON.parse(hours) + 12;
    return hours24 + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  } else {
    return time;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is how i implement this :

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    // Write your code here
   const arr =s.split(":")
   const isAM = arr[2].includes("AM")
   if(isAM) {
      arr[0]=arr[0].padStart(2, '0');
      arr[2]=arr[2].replace("AM","");  
        if(arr[0]==="12")  arr[0] ="00"
           
    }else{
        arr[0]=(+arr[0]+12).toString();
        arr[2]=arr[2].replace("PM","");  
        if(arr[0]==="24")  arr[0] ="12"
    }
   return(arr.join(":"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the simplest way. Here's a step-by-step on what's happening:

1. You get the time in 12-hour format
2. Split the time by timestamp & meridian
3. If it's midnight, prepend `00` otherwise print just the timestamp
4. If it's noon, just print the timestamp otherwise add the hour with `12`

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    // 07:05:45PM
    const timeInAmPmArray = s.split(/(AM|PM)/) // ['07:05:45', 'PM', '']
    const hour = Number(timeInAmPmArray[0].split(':')[0]) // 7
    const amOrPm = timeInAmPmArray[1] // PM
    let timeIn24Hour = ''
    if(amOrPm === 'AM') {
      timeIn24Hour = hour === 12 ? `00:${timeInAmPmArray[0].split(':').slice(1).join(':')}` : timeInAmPmArray[0]
    } else {
      timeIn24Hour = hour === 12 ? timeInAmPmArray[0] : `${hour + 12}:${timeInAmPmArray[0].split(':').slice(1).join(':')}`
      // timeIn24Hour = 19:05:45
    }
    return timeIn24Hour
}
    
timeConversion('07:05:45PM')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Here is brute force kind of solution which works for me

```
const time = '11:8AM';

function convertTo24HrsFormat(time) {
    // write your solution here
    let timeWithPM = time.endsWith("PM");
    
    if (time.includes('P')) {
        let minuteVal = time.slice(time.indexOf(':')+1, time.indexOf('P'));
      
      if(minuteVal.length === 1) {
        minuteVal = `0${minuteVal}`;
        let result = time.slice(0, time.indexOf(':'));
        time = `${result}:${minuteVal}PM`;
        console.log("CHECKING123====>>>>", time);
      }
    } 
    
    if (time.includes('A')) {
        let minuteVal = time.slice(time.indexOf(':')+1, time.indexOf('A'));
      if(minuteVal.length === 1) {
        minuteVal = `0${minuteVal}`;
        let result = time.slice(0, time.indexOf(':'));
        time = `${result}:${minuteVal}AM`;
      }
    } 
        

    if(timeWithPM) {
        let result = findHour(time);
        return result;
    }

    if(!timeWithPM) {
        let result = withAM(time);
        return result;
    }

    return;
}

function findHour(time) {
    let hour = time.slice(0, time.indexOf(':'));
    if(parseInt(hour) < 12)
        hour = parseInt(hour)+12;
    if (hour.toString().length === 1)
        hour = `0${hour}`;
    let removeHourWithPM = time.split(":").pop();
    removeHourWithPM = `${hour}:${removeHourWithPM}`;
    // console.log("CHECKING-----",hour);
    return removeHourWithPM.slice(0, -2);
}

function withAM(time) {

        let isTwelve = time.slice(0, time.indexOf(':'));
    if(isTwelve == '12') {
        let get12 = time.split(':').pop();
        let result = get12.slice(0, -2);
        return `00:${result}`
    }
    
        let hour = time.slice(0, time.indexOf(':'));
    if(hour.length === 1) {
        hour = `0${hour}`;
      let removeHourWithSingledigit = time.split(":").pop();
      removeHourWithSingledigit = `${hour}:${removeHourWithSingledigit}`;
      return removeHourWithSingledigit.slice(0, -2);
    }
    
    return time.slice(0, -2);
}

console.log(`Converted time: ${convertTo24HrsFormat(time)}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeConversion(amPmStr = '') {
    const time = amPmStr.replace(/(AM|PM|am|pm)/, (match) => ' ' + match);
    const randomDate = "September 25, 2018 ";
    const date = new Date(randomDate + time);
    const hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const mins = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const secs = date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a simple code -

```js
const time = '12:10AM';

function convertTo24HrsFormat(time) {
    let [hour, modifier] = time.split(":");
    let min = parseInt(modifier).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let index = modifier.toLowerCase().indexOf('m');
    let meridian = modifier.slice(index - 1);
    hour = parseInt(hour);

    if (hour === 12) {
        hour = 00;
    }

    if (meridian == 'PM') {
        hour = hour + 12;
    }

    hour = hour.toString().padStart(2, '0');


    let time24hr = `${hour}:${min}`;

    return time24hr;
}

console.log(`Converted time: ${convertTo24HrsFormat(time)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

A well tested approach:

```
// example, s = 12:34:56PM
function timeConversion(s) {
    let designator, clock, hhmmss, hh, mm, ss, mil; // declare variables
    designator = s.slice(-2); // returns AM or PM
    hhmmss = s.substring(0, s.length-2) // returns hh:mm:ss
    clock = hhmmss.split(':'); // returns array of [hh,mm,ss]
    hh = designator === 'AM' 
       ? (parseInt(clock[0]) === 12 ? '00' : clock[0]) 
       : (parseInt(clock[0]) === 12 ? '12' : parseInt(clock[0]) + 12);
    mm = clock[1];
    ss = clock[2];
    mil = [hh,mm,ss].join(':').toString();
    return mil
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is TypeScript solution. Remark it ignores seconds.

```js
/**
 * Safe parsing of american 12-hour time (ex.: 4:45 PM) to ISO-8601 24-hour time (such as 16:45:00).
 * This method ignores seconds
 *
 * @param dateStr - american 12-hour time
 * @private
 */
export const parseAmericanTimeToIso = (timeStr: string): string => {
  if (timeStr) {
    try {
      const [time, modifier] = timeStr.split(' ');
      const [hourStr, minute] = time.split(':');
      const hour = parseInt(hourStr) + (modifier === 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
      return `${hour}:${minute}:00`;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error parsing 12-hour to ISO-8601 24-hour time: ', timeStr);
      return null;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(parseAmericanTimeToIso("10:45 PM"); // 22:45:00
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: This answer does not handle seconds**

Here is my solution, using regex to split. Simple and short:

```
convert24To12(time){
    let [hours, minutes, modifier] = time.split(/ |:/);
    if (modifier === 'PM') {
        hours = `${parseInt(hours, 10) + 12}`;      
    }
    time = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Answer is wrong for '12:00:00AM'.