# HTML5 input type time setting values not working

Tags: html, input, time, format

I have a form with input type time. I am trying to set values. But it is not showing. Here is my code.

```
<input type="time" name="exit" id="teacher-entry-exit-form-exit-input" class="form-control" value="08:56 AM" required="">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using google:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_value.asp
http://jsfiddle.net/q29qt4zg/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36758501/4640499

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's based on 24-hour time, therefore use `value="08:56"` for AM and `value="20:56"` for PM.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rk8qrx3u/)

```
<input type="time" value="08:56">
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html

Comment: its possible to insert AM Or PM   like this  <input type="time" value="08:56 AM">
 <input type="time" value="08:56 PM">

Answer (score 4):

[Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6000966/stephen-romero), [Giri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10384879/giri-dharan),
all you have to do, in order to get AM/PM set, is to convert your 12-hour time string into 24-hour one, before passing it to the value attribute of input [type=time].

Here is a quick [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm) how to convert 12-hour -> 24-hour time string.

```js
    const am_pm_to_hours = time => {
        let hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        let minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
        const AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
        if (AMPM.toLowerCase() === "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
        if (AMPM.toLowerCase() === "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;

        let sHours = hours.toString();
        let sMinutes = minutes.toString();
        if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
        if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;

        return `${sHours}:${sMinutes}`;
    }
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
<input class="form-control" type="time" name="time" value="<?=date("H:i", strtotime($dbObject['time'])); ?>" />
```

In this way, one can fetch the time column and display it like this using PHP and mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Convert AM/PM Time string to 24 Hours Format. Example 9:30 PM to 21:30

```js
function convertTimeFrom12To24(timeStr) {
  var colon = timeStr.indexOf(':');
  var hours = timeStr.substr(0, colon),
      minutes = timeStr.substr(colon+1, 2),
      meridian = timeStr.substr(colon+4, 2).toUpperCase();
    
  var hoursInt = parseInt(hours, 10),
      offset = meridian == 'PM' ? 12 : 0;
  
  if (hoursInt === 12) {
    hoursInt = offset;
  } else {
    hoursInt += offset;
  }
  return hoursInt + ":" + minutes;
}
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("12:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("12:00 PM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("11:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("01:00 AM"));
console.log(convertTimeFrom12To24("01:00 PM"));
```