# how to set time in input field of type time in angular6?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my `angular6` project i am receiving time in string like `01:00 AM`. And i have `inputs` of type `time` like this

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Open Time" [(ngModel)]="hour.open">
```

And i am trying to set this time`(01:00 AM)` to my field but it's not setting. How can i set that value in my `input`?

Comment: consider entering the title of your question into Google....

Comment: I got no help from there that's why i asked here

Comment: Strange....I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827801/how-to-set-default-time-to-html-input-field-of-type-time-in-ionic which has the gist of what you need.... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827801/how-to-set-default-time-to-html-input-field-of-type-time-in-ionic and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546447/bind-an-input-with-type-datetime-local-to-a-date-property-in-angular-2