# Jquery How to check today time greater then use given time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

How to check time conditionin Jquery

```
 var startTime="20:02:55"; // or 12:34
 var endTime ="21:02:55"  // or 1:34 
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

if(time >startTime || time < endTiime){
 $("#a").html("show Box");
}else{
 $("#a").html("Expire BOx");
}
```

How to check 12 hour and 24 hour condition   also?
is it correct? i need  am, pm format check please can anyone help me?

Comment: var hours = date.getHours();  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

Comment: You need to also convert `startTime` and `endTime` to Date objects so that they can be easily compared. At the moment you're comparing a Date to a string which is going to give odd results.

Comment: Rory is correct. I'd recommend [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for parsing time strings like that.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan please can you answer me the convert starttime and endtime to date?

Comment: How to check 12 hour and 24 hour also?

Comment: try this [convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code. I am appending to show both behaviour. 
[Here is DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkcchqbb/2/)

```
test("20:02:55", "21:02:55");
test("13:02:55", "15:02:55");

function test(start_time, end_time) {
    var dt = new Date();

    //convert both time into timestamp
    var stt = new Date((dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear() + " " + start_time);

    stt = stt.getTime();
    var endt = new Date((dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear() + " " + end_time);
    endt = endt.getTime();

    var time = dt.getTime();

    if (time > stt && time < endt) {
        $("#a").append("<br> show Box ");

    } else {
        $("#a").append("<br> Expire BOx ");

    }
}
```

Comment: @angu if it has solved your problem.. please accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
I took the logic to print 'Show Box' if the current time is in between the start and end time. else viceversa.

```js
var startTime="20:02:55"; // or 12:34
 var endTime ="21:02:55"  // or 1:34 
var dt = new Date();
var st = new Date('00','00','00',startTime.split(':')[0],startTime.split(':')[1],startTime.split(':')[2]);
var et = new Date('00','00','00',endTime.split(':')[0],endTime.split(':')[1],endTime.split(':')[2]);
if(dt.getTime() >st.getTime() && dt.getTime() < et.getTime()){
alert("show Box");
}else{
alert("Expire BOx");
}
```