# Transform 12h clock values to 24h clock values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, ecmascript-5

Given a number of strings that contain clock values such as "12.00 am - 4.00 pm", "4.00 - 9.00 am" and "5.00 am - 9.00 am, 1.00 - 8.00 pm", how can I transform each of them into their 24h equivalent, in this case "12:00-16:00", "4.00-9.00" and "5.00-9.00, 13.00-20.00"?

Comment: this shouldn't be terribly difficult if you know a little [modulo math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You definitely need to show some effort though.

Comment: Have you tried searching already? This may lead you in the correct direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm

Comment: I tried dividing the array into different parts using substring and indexOf, then adding 12 if the extension is pm. The problem is that the format is not always the same so the parts get messed up. I also can't target the "-" character with indexOf since it is some special sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "12.00 am - 4.00 pm\n4.00 - 9.00 am\n5.00 am - 9.00 am\n1.00 - 8.00 pm";
var reg = /(\d+\.\d+)( am| pm|)? - (\d+\.\d+) (am|pm)/g;
str.replace(reg,function myfun(g,g1,g2,g3,g4){
    if(!g2){
        g2 = g4
    }
    if(g2=='pm'){
        g1 = (parseInt(g1)+12)+".00";
    }
    if(g4=='pm'){
        g3 = (parseInt(g3)+12)+".00";
    }
    return g1+" - "+g3;
});
```

I tried it with javascript and regex.

```
Result:
    12.00 - 16.00
    4.00 - 9.00
    5.00 - 9.00
    13.00 - 20.00
```