# I need to validate the format of time AM|PM

Tags: javascript, time-format

I have this code but its not working.How can i check if time is in AM or PM.

```
var time = $(id1).val();

var hrs = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);

var mnts = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);

var format = time.match(/\s(.*)$/);
//alert(format);
//alert(time);

if (format == "PM" && hrs < 12) {
     hrs = hrs + 12;
}    

if (format == "AM" && hrs == 12) hrs = hrs - 12;
```

Comment: what is the value in time variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm)

Answer (score 0):

You made a copy/paste mistake from my answer from three years ago ([convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm/15083891#15083891))

```
var format = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
```

Don't forget `[1]`

Comment: thanks a lot man.you helped me then and you are still here.Can you please drop that same code once more here