# How to hide past time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button with name Today When I click on that there should not be display past time.

How can I do that?

My code:

```js
$('.today').click(function() {
  $('.custom_time li').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="today">today</button>

<div class="custom_time">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">10:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">11:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">12:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">01:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">02:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">03:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">04:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">05:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">06:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">07:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like your code is already doing what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: @glhr look at his current code, there is no logic inside, he just hided everything

Comment: when i click on today button there is all times hide but i want to just hide past time as per current time.

Comment: you mean hide only times less than current time ?

Comment: @George Bailey Yes

Comment: @RohitVerma please add the desired behaviour in your post.

Comment: @RohitVerma please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the current hour and compare it with each `timeNumeric`, you need also to check for the "pm/am" period hours, like:

```js
$('.today').click(function(){
  var hour, period;
  var current_hour = new Date().getHours();

  $('.custom_time li').each(function() {
    period = $("small", this).text() === "pm" ? 12 : 0;
    hour = parseInt($(".timeNumeric", this).text().split(':')[0]) + period;

    if (hour <= current_hour || hour === 24) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="today">today</button>

<div class="custom_time">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">10:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">11:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">12:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">01:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">02:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">03:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">04:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">05:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">06:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">07:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't it hide 12:00pm also ? as here it is 2:56PM ?

Comment: there is 12:00 pm also should be hide because it is less than current time

Comment: Ah, I missed the am/pm

Comment: Thanks @Zakaria Acharki now its working fine exactly what is want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try filter

Note I converted the am/pm to 24 hours using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197728/295783)

```js
const pad = (num) => ("0"+num).slice(-2);
const convertTime12to24 = (time12h) => { const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' '); let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':'); if (hours === '12') hours = '00'; if (modifier.toUpperCase() === 'PM') hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12; return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(minutes)}`; }
const padTime = (d) => `${pad(d.getHours())}:${pad(d.getMinutes())}`;

$('.today').on("click",() => {
  const now = padTime(new Date());
  $('#output').text(` Filtering on ${now}`)
  $('.custom_time li').filter((_,elm) => {
    const $t = $(elm).find('.timeNumeric');
    const text = convertTime12to24($t.text()+' '+$t.next().text());
    return text<now;
  }).hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="today">today</button><span id="output"></span>

<div class="custom_time">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">10:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">11:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">12:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">01:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">02:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">03:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">04:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">05:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">06:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">07:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: still hiding everything

Comment: what about 3,4,5,6 PM  ?

Comment: I think it is. 12:00PM is less than 3:00PM No ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this...I think that piece of code can be improved a lot but hey, that's a start.

```js
$('.today').click(function() {
  $('.custom_time li').each(function() {
    var hour = $(this).find('.timeNumeric').html();
    hour = hour.split(':')[0];
    hour = parseInt(hour);
    var isMorning = $(this).find('small').html() == 'am';
    if (!isMorning && hour != 12) hour += 12;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (hour <= currentDate.getHours()) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="today">today</button>

<div class="custom_time">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">10:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">11:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">12:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">01:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">02:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">03:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">04:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">05:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">06:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">07:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there is 12:00 pm also should be hide because it is less than current time

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you to do is, Just take a random date (without the time part).

Now set the current date's `minutes`, `hours` , `seconds` for that date.

Now create a date (date part same as above) with time of that mentioned in your `li` and compare them with simple `<` or `>` and you should be able to get what you want

```js
$('.today').click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  
  var today = new Date("11/24/1993");
  
  today.setHours(d.getHours());
  today.setMinutes(d.getMinutes());
  today.setSeconds(d.getSeconds());
   
  $('.custom_time li').each(function() {
       var tempDate = new Date("11/24/1993 "+$(this).text());
       
        
       
       if(tempDate < today)
           $(this).hide()
      
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="today">today</button>

<div class="custom_time">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">10:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">11:00</span> <small>am</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">12:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">01:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">02:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">03:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">04:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">05:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">06:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="time"><span class="timeNumeric">07:00</span> <small>pm</small></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to create a date each time. Just the string HH:MM (with or without am/pm) is enough since it sorts correctly

Comment: ohk. didn't know that. Thanks :)