# How to convert am/pm date to 24 hour time

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which returns a time in format "Thu, 26 Nov 2020, 3:00pm" to format YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00 format:

```
       var originalStartDate = ("#originalStartTime").text().split(",")[1];
       var originalStartTime = $.trim($("#originalStartTime").text().split(",")[2]).replace('pm','');
       var dateTime = new Date(originalStartDate + ' ' + originalStartTime);
       var removeMilliseconds = dateTime.toISOString().split('.')[0] + " ";
       var formattedDate = removeMilliseconds.replace('T', " ");

       return formattedDate;
```

However, as this is 3:00pm I want it to be 15:00:00. How can I do this in the most straightforward way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`momentJS`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for this simple job;

```js
const input = "Thu, 26 Nov 2020, 3:00pm";
const mom = moment(input, 'ddd, D MMM, HH:mma');

const format = mom.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(format);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> 2020-11-26 15:00:00

Comment: Of course even the [writers of moment now consider it "legacy"](https://momentjs.com/docs/) this this probably isn't a good choice in 2020