# Formatting 12 hour time (h:mm A) to 24 hour time (HH:mm:00) in day.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, dayjs

I am trying to make a time conversion function that takes time in as "h:mm A" and converts it to military time (HH:mm:00) in day.js, but am struggling to figure it out. I was able to complete this task without dayjs but can't quite figure it out with dayjs. Here is my attempt at it:

The 00 is there as I want the seconds to default to 00. Thank you!

```js
function convertToMilitaryTime(formattedTime) {
  if (formattedTime) { //formattedTime is 'h:mm A'
    const formatted = dayjs(formattedTime, "h:mm A")
    return day(formattedTime, ['h:mm A']).format("HH:mm:00")
  }
  return formattedTime;
}
console.log(convertToMilitaryTime("10:24 AM")); // not a valid date string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - I removed the typescript to make it a runnable snippet. You had a typo with the quotes, but your code stull does not work. What is a valid date input and what is the function `day`  you are calling? Please fix the script to a [mcve]

Comment: The A that I am using is the dayjs formatting for AM/PM @mplungjan

Comment: A valid date input would be say "10:24 AM" or "8:55 PM"

Comment: So what is `day()` - I updated your snippet with 10:24 AM

Comment: @mplungjan I'm asking the question because of the fact that I couldn't get it to work. Day() was just modeled after the approach that would be applicable to momentjs. Not too sure how to make this code work though for intended purposes.

Comment: [Or without using dayjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prepend any date to make a valid dayjs date object

Note: this is the lazy way of allowing a time string. To adhere to the documentation of dayJS. [look at the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821515/295783)

[Or don't use dayJS at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm)

```js
const ampm2military = ampm => ampm ? dayjs(`1/1/1 ${ampm}`).format("HH:mm:00") : null;

console.log(ampm2military("1:24 PM"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

- the function name is `dayjs`, not `day`
- this formatting requires a plugin (`customParseFormat` - "String + Format" depends on this plugin; it's noted on [the top part of the docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) (in yellow)); you have to load this plugin for the syntax to work
- after loading the plugin, you have to **extend** `dayjs` with the new capabilities

(Edited the code: removed the double call of `dayjs` in the conditional.)

```js
// extend dayjs with the loaded customParseFormat plugin
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat)

function convertToMilitaryTime(formattedTime) {
  if (formattedTime) { //formattedTime is 'h:mm A'
    // the function name is dayjs, not day
    return dayjs(formattedTime, 'h:mm A').format("HH:mm:00")
  }
  return formattedTime;
}
console.log(convertToMilitaryTime("10:24 AM")); // not a valid date string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- load the required plugin: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.11.3/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

### EDIT: updated code

```js
// extend dayjs with the loaded customParseFormat plugin
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat)

const convertToMilitaryTime = (ft) => dayjs(ft, "h:mm A", "en", true).isValid() ? dayjs(ft, 'h:mm A').format("HH:mm:00") : ft

console.log(convertToMilitaryTime("10:24 AM")); // not a valid date string
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- load the required plugin: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.11.3/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan you may be right in this case - but I don't know what OP is using dayjs for, what other formatting issues s/he might have in the tasklist; also, this relies on the official API of dayjs, and not on a smart solution. Extensible, reliable, repeatable (by less skilled devs too). But I agree: kbytes for a simple formatting may be a hefty price :)

Comment: Why do you call it twice?

Comment: @mplungjan let me keep that as a secret ;) (actually, I realized that the code that I copied is not really optimal only after I closed the editor. then I was just lazy to correct it.)

Comment: but now I updated the answer with a bit updated code

Comment: @mplungjan because the "crappy version" is the original one (OP's) corrected so it works.  My experience is that this way it's easier for people to understand the changes needed.

Comment: But then at least remove the double call ?

Comment: @mplungjan it really bugs you, doesn't it? :) I removed it - this way it's almost there where my updated example is.

Comment: Yeah it did because you made me aware that my solution was almost a hack, then  I got a bit obsessed that your solution which is  perhaps better or at least more adhering to the manual was not optimal. I linked to your answer from mine, you see